# How to match stuff enclosed by ``` but the ending ``` is optional?

Tags: regex

I now have this pattern

````
const pattern = /```([^`]+?)```/gm
const data = "here is an exmaple```code1```here is an exmaple```code2```here is an exmaple```code3"
````

It will match code1 and code2 but *not* code3. In another word it will match perfectly enclosed ones. I want code3 to be matched as well. One rule I think is important here is partially enclosed ones (like code3) will never be in the middle, it will only at the end of the data stream.

How to do it?

P.S. I know that I can use this...

````
```([^`]+?)```|```([^`]+?)$
````

Comment: Try `\`\`\`([^\`]+?)(\`\`\`|$)`

Comment: If the ending ticks are optional, then your regex wouldn't be matching stuff *enclosed*, would it?

Comment: If you are dealing with Markdown, then a Markdown parser is probably the way to go.

Comment: @KenWhite Normally you are correct but again, the ending is not optional in my case. You can think of this as the ending is either another ``` or the end of string. and yes it matches. try ```([^`]+?)```|```([^`]+?)$ with both sometext ```code``` and sometext ```code  , you will see

Comment: @InSync i'm dealing with chatgpt output...yes it's markdown but i don't like to add dependencies...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One pattern that matches your requirements is

````
/```([^`]+)(?:```)?/g
````

````js
const regex = /```([^`]+)(?:```)?/g

const str = "here is an exmaple```code1```here is an exmaple```code2```here is an exmaple```code3";

console.log(str.match(regex));
````

The output will be

````
[
  "```code1```",
  "```code2```",
  "```code3"
]
````

Comment: thanks! that's exactly what i'm looking for. one little thing, i was using it to match returns from openai webapi, so my initial pattern was wrong, the capture should be /```([\s\S]+)(?:```)?/g  because in code example it will have char `